# Can IBM worklight be used to create a pure mobile web application (not hybrid)?

Tags: user-interface, frameworks, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I would like to build a mobile app based only on a UI framework ( dojo, kendo etc..) and use PHP, node.js etc.as my backend server side tools.

What I understand is that Worklight introduces its own wrapper javascript framework over the existing UI framework ( dojo, kendo, etc.)

Can IBM worklight be used to create a pure mobile web application (no hybrid) using a UI framework like Dojo, Kendo UI etc?

Also, I understand that worklight server (which i suppose is not free) needs to be installed at the server end.

Why i would want to use worklight?
As observerd in the tutorials it provides complete end to end environment for mobile app development ( IDE, Build capabilities, optimization, testing will various mobile device emulators) in a single enviroment, which I would like to leverage for development.

Comment: There are many compelling reasons to use Worklight ... but no, you can't write a Worklight application without bringing in Worklight infrastructure.  But the same is true for *ANY* framework.  STRONG SUGGESTION: look at HTML 5 ["Mobile Application Developer Platforms"](http://i-proving.com/2012/10/19/all-we-are-saying-is-give-madps-a-chance/)  like PhoneGap, Appcelerator and jQuery Mobile as well: http://www.developereconomics.com/pros-cons-top-5-cross-platform-tools/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the tools you mention assume at their basis that you are developing a *Worklight-based* Hybrid application. So no, you cannot create a pure web app in Worklight, w/out the added Worklight-generated files. The build tool, the testing tool, the optimization tools, all work on Worklight-based apps.

Also, it's not that Worklight *Server* specifically costs money, *Worklight* costs money... you may not publish a Worklight application (either B2C or B2E) w/out a license.

You can evaluate Worklight by using the Developer Edition that you download from Eclipse Marketplace, but at the end you must purchase a license if you intend on going public.